# Use textfield instead of submit button to pass data

Tags: php, html

I just want to know if there is another way to pass form from php using textfield instead of submit button, because I want to send my updated data using  textfield or password so the user will just enter the textfield after typing this is how my code looks like

```
if(isset($_POST['textfield']))
{
   echo "send data";
}

<input type = "text" id = "textfield">
```

Comment: you can use ajax onblur event to submit a form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute a javascript function on textfield's onblur event and submit your form on its blur event.

```
<form id="form">
<input type = "text" id = "textfield" onblur="submitMe()">
</form>

<script>
function submitMe() {
$("#form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: wow thanks i just found out now that the jquery has a submit function this information is a big help for me thanks

Comment: pleasure ..am glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code, `$_POST['textfield']` will always be unset.

Use,

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" name="textfield">
```

`isset($_POST['submit'])` is just a convention, just to check that the POST data is coming from form - not anywhere else.

So, ofcourse you can, but be aware of securrity problems.

Comment: can you tell me what could be the possible threats for security ?

Comment: How would his form be submitted to server with data without javascript and only with PHP code? @marmeladze

Comment: @sysquare a submit button or  listening for keyup event on textfield might be options.

Comment: For that you will need Jquery/Javascript. You cant do that with only server side languages. Your answer is invalid.

Comment: @unknown it's a good practice to use unique tokens (csrf tokens) to prevent submitbots. in that case, you'll check `if(isset($_POST['unique_token'])) { //then checking other elements of array }`

Comment: @sysquare what is wrong with javascript? :) no need to notice that, for every kind of browser interaction, one can only use javascript. i don't think the question owner don't know that - he just asked for, is it ok not to check $_POST['submit'] is set or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to send the form

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

    </script>
<body>
    Hello World!
<form action="find.php" id="myForm">
<input type = "text" id = "textfield" onblur="myfunction()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```